# Display images when hovering over another image

Tags: css, image, hover

I have an image and a list that contains images, what i want to do is when i hover on the first image the list appears, how can i do that using css? here is my code:

```css
ul{
display: none
}

.hoveroverme:hover{
ul{
display:block
}
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="hoveroverme">

<ul class="list-inline list-unstyled">
<li><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"></li>
<li><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"></li>
<li><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to affect other elements when a div is hovered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-a-div-is-hovered)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a sibling selector. In this case, you can use either the adjacent sibling selector (`+`), or general sibling selector (`~`).

```css
ul {
  display: none
}

.hoveroverme:hover + ul {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="hoveroverme">

<ul class="list-inline list-unstyled">
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use sibling selector here `+` or `~`

```
ul{
display: none
}

.hoveroverme:hover ~ ul{
display:block
}
```

`+` will only select the first element that is immediately preceded by the former selector.

`~` selector all the sibling preceded by the former selector.